# If $a + \frac{1}{a} = -1$, then the value of $(1-a+a^2)(1+a-a^2)$ is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers

> If $a + \frac{1}{a} = -1$ then the value of $(1-a+a^2)(1+a-a^2)$ is?

Ans. 4

What I have  tried:

\begin{align}
a + \frac{1}{a} &= -1 \\
\implies a^2 + 1 &= -a \tag 1 \\
\end{align}

which means

\begin{align}
(1-a+a^2)(1+a-a^2) &=(-2a)(-2a^2) \\
&=4a^{3}
\end{align}

as $1 + a^{2} = -a$ and $1 + a = -a^{2}$ from $(1)$.

Comment: That's strange. According to AMGM inequality, for any real $a\ne 0$, $a+1/a\geq 2$ for $a>0$ and $a+1/a<-2$ for $a<0$. Unless you're assuming $a \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @GautamShenoy Maybe $a$ is a complex number. On solving the quadratic eq, I am getting a complex number. And this should be true because the discriminant of the eq is negative. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without solving the quadratic:

$$ a^3 = - a^2 - a = a + 1 - a = 1 $$

which was found by using the equation $a^2 + a + 1 = 0$ twice. This means that $a$ is a non-real cube root of unity.

Comment: Sir, when I am solving the quadratic equation by calculator, I get $a$ as a complex number. How ever through this method, a turns out to be 1. Why is this contradicting?

Comment: Just because $a^3 = 1$, doesn't mean $a = 1$. There are other solutions to $a^3 = 1$, and these have enough importance that they are given a name: the solutions to $a^3 = 1$ are the cube roots of unity.

Answer (score 2):

It is well-known from high school the roots of the quadratic $a^2+a+1=0$ are the non-real cube roots of unity, hence $a^3=1$.

Comment: Sir, this means $a$ can be 1. But when I am solving the quadratic by calculator, I get a complex number. Why is this contradictory?

Comment: If $a=1$, you never can get $a+1/a=-1$.

Comment: Yes true.......

Answer (score 2):

$a^3=1$.

Thus, $$(1-a+a^2)(1+a-a^2)=-2a\cdot(-2a^2)=4$$

Comment: Sir, this means $a$ can be 1. But when I am solving the quadratic by calculator, I get a complex number. Why is this contradictory?

Comment: Sir, how do we get $a^3=1$

Comment: @Soumee Because $a^3-1=(a-1)(a^2+a+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Just solve the quadratic $(1)$ to get $a$, then substitute $a$ back in the original expression or $4a^3$.

Also, since $a^3-1=(a-1)(a^2+a+1),$ $a^3=1$.

In more detail, from $(1)$,
$$\begin{align}a&=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4}}{2} \\
&=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}.\end{align}$$
Now
$$\begin{align}
a^2&=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}\times \frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
&=\frac{1\mp i2\sqrt{3}-3}{4} \\
&=\frac{-1\mp i\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{align}$$ and

$$\begin{align}
a^3&=\frac{-1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}\times \frac{-1\mp i\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
&=\frac{1\pm i\sqrt{3}\mp i\sqrt{3}+3}{4} \\
&=1.
\end{align}$$

Comment: If we solve eq (1), then we get a complex number, which would make the solution complex.

Comment: @Soumee, no, it would not.

Comment: Sir, can you please work that out for me. When I am trying to do it, its getting complicated.

Comment: @Soumee, I've worked it out for you.